# Remove lambda expression

Tags: java, android, lambda

I am new to lambda expressions and I have this code to scan Eddystone beacons and I want to remove the lambda expression from it. I don't know exactly how they work. Can anyone help?

```java
beaconManager.getRegionViewModel(myRegion).getRangedBeacons().observe(this, beacons -> {
    noBeacons.setText(String.valueOf(beacons.size()));

    for (Beacon beacon : beacons) {
        if (uuids.contains(beacon))
            continue;
        uuids.add(beacon);
        if (beacon.getServiceUuid() == 0xfeaa && beacon.getBeaconTypeCode() == 0x00) {
            // This is a Eddystone-UID frame
            Identifier namespaceId = beacon.getId1();
            Identifier instanceId = beacon.getId2();
            logthis("I see a beacon transmitting namespace id: " + namespaceId +
                    " and instance id: " + instanceId +
                    " approximately " + beacon.getDistance() + " meters away.");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second parameter of the `observe` method is a functional interface, thats why you can put a lambda in it. Most likely it will be `Consumer<T>` from the  [java.util.function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/package-summary.html) package because it takes just one argument `beacons`. If you want that lambda removed (i guess you mean replaced) you would need to define a class which implements this functional interface, like:

```
class Helper implements Consumer<Beacon[]> {
    @Override
    public void accept​(Beacon[] beacons) {
        // lambda body here
    }
}
```

and give an instance of the class to `observe`:

```
beaconManager.getRegionViewModel(myRegion).getRangedBeacons().observe(this, new Helper());
```

You could also do it in a more inline fashion with anonymous interface implementations, like so:

```
beaconManager.getRegionViewModel(myRegion).getRangedBeacons().observe(this, new Consumer<Beacon[]>() {
    public void accept(Beacon[] beacons) {
        // lambda body here
    }
});
```

But now you see there is no point in going this detour if not forced (read Java <8).
Just learn a bit lambda syntax which is basically `() -> {}` and it does all the hassle for you.